# Serializer containing nested objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write a serializer in a way that it returns a friendship object including all friendship_creator and friendship_friend fields (firstname, lastname, email), not just ids.

The user model is the default auth.user model and friendship models looks like this:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
        creator = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', related_name = 'friendship_creator')
        friend = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', related_name = 'friendship_friend')
        status = models.IntegerField()
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

serializers.py

```
class FriendshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
                model = Friendship
```

Current response object:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "status": 2,
        "created": "2015-05-03T17:33:05.027652Z",
        "creator": 3,
        "friend": 4
}
```

I'd like that "creator" and "friend" would contain the whole user object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement a serializer for the User model. Say UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Then explicitly declare 'creator' and 'friend' attributes on the FriendshipSerializer, assigning instances of the UserSerializer:

```
class FriendshipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = UserSerializer()
    friend = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
            model = Friendship
```

It's fairly clear in [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).